# Adding -std=c++11 to compiler options in Anjuta 3.4.3

Tags: c++, c++11, anjuta

I'm fairly far in a project using GTKmm atm, and I'm trying to add in some code a friend of mine have been working on. However I'm getting this error:

> error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be
>   enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options

However I can't find anywhere that will actually let me add these compiler options.

Adding it to `Build -> Configure Project` only yields a:
`Error: unrecognized option 'std=c++11'`.

Anyone more familiar with this IDE who might be able to help?

Comment: Your compiler is probably not compatible with c++11 as it is too old. Try c++0x. If that doesn't help you really should get a new compiler.

Comment: Anjuta _what_? [There have been loads of versions.](https://download.gnome.org/sources/anjuta/)

Comment: Know of a reasonable IDE on Linux which runs GTKmm other than Anjuta?

Comment: Lightning: Sorry, its 3.4.3. Added to title as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the commandline options start with a '-'. So the option is `-std=c++11` (See `man gcc`).

Adding an option in `Build -> Configure Project` must be done like this

```
CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11'
```

You can also go to `Project | Project options`, then select your target in the top box. An options should appear 'More options'. Click on that, and you can enter `-std=c++11` in the option field you want to use (probably `Compiler flags`).

It works here, but I have `gcc` version 4.8.x