# how do I add -std=c++11 to the compiler options in my Qt Creator?

Tags: linux, qt, c++11, gcc, qt-creator

**Note:** same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683355/how-do-i-add-std-c11-to-the-compiler-options-in-my-netbeans-ide) question but for other IDE

I'm trying to compile my Qt Project in **Qt Creator** IDE but when I click to build, it shows:

> This file requires compiler and library support \
>   for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled \
>   with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

When I go to Project -> Build and Run -> Build steps -> Additional arguments and add `-std=c++11` and compile it again, I got this on the Compile output:

> 11:45:37: Running steps for project Youtube-dl-gui...
>   11:45:37: Starting: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake" /home/fabio/criação/Youtube-dl-gui/Youtube-dl-gui.pro -r -spec linux-g++-64 CONFIG+=debug -std=c++11
>   Usage: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake [mode] [options] [files]
>   ...
>   [here it shows more options of the usage]
>   ...
>   ***Unknown option -std=c++11
>   11:45:37: The process "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake" exited with code 1.
>   Error while building/deploying project Youtube-dl-gui (kit: Desktop)
>   When executing step "qmake"
>   11:45:37: Elapsed time: 00:00.

In my MakeFile config file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Youtube-dl-gui
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += '-std=c++11'
```

I already tried what was proposed in these threads:

[Adding -std=c++11 to compiler options in Anjuta 3.4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851717/adding-std-c11-to-compiler-options-in-anjuta-3-4-3)

[Qmake doesn't use stdc++11 compilation flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689371/qmake-doesnt-use-stdc11-compilation-flag)

**Update**

- Changing to `CONFIG += c++11` didn't worked
- My compiler on project is `/usr/bin/g++` and if I run `/usr/bin/g++ --version` returns **5.4.0 20160609**

**Update 2**

- I think my gcc have support to c++11 since in NetBeans I can build and run programs in c++11 standard using the same `/usr/bin/g++` binary.
- As the compile output shows, the command being run is `"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake" /home/fabio/criação/Youtube-dl-gui/Youtube-dl-gui.pro -r -spec linux-g++-64 CONFIG+=debug -std=c++11` and it seems that it is my `qmake version 3.0` that doesn't have support for c++11, I guess

Comment: If you upgrade to gcc-6, things will be simpler since it defaults to C++14 ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As described here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html , you should add `CONFIG += c++11` in your .pro file

Comment: I already tried this, didn't worked. Maybe I am missing some packages to install?

Comment: Are you sure that in your project Kit, the C++ compiler is set to g++ version 5.4.0 ?

Comment: Yes, in the project kit manager, the path to the compiler is `/usr/bin/g++`. If I run `/usr/bin/g++ --version` it returns me 5.4

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the apostrophes around -std=c++11.

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += '-std=c++11'
```

Should be

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

Comment: Looks like your compiler don't support c++11 are you certain it uses /usr/bin/g++?. My setup is qt 5.2.1, qmake 3.0 with g++ 4.8.4.

Comment: Yes because NetBeans also uses `/usr/bin/g++` as compiler and a project set to standard c++11 compiles and run normally.

Comment: I get the error "***Unknown option -std=c++11" when I run qmake -std=c++11.